# mysql joining table and receiving one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

```
The table 'category':

cat_id   category
1        mobile
2        watch
..        ..
```

and the 'category_brand' table:

```
product_id   cat_id
1              1
2              1
3              2
..             ..
```

and i have this code

```
public function actionEdit($id)
    {
         $sql="SELECT * FROM category_brand INNER JOIN category ON category_brand.cat_id=category.cat_id WHERE category_brand.product_id=$id";
         $editcat=Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryOne();
         print_r($editcat->category);die;
   }
```

I am trying to retreice the category of the product_id. what am i doing wrong here? The product_id is auto_increment value. but i am getting  'Trying to get property of non-object'

Comment: Your query looks fine, which would leave the YII code as a suspect for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`queryOne()` returns `array|false`, not `ActiveRecord` object

look at result of `print_r($editcat);`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#queryOne()-detail

If you want AR object as result, use its realtions

```
$editCategory = Category::find()
      ->joinWith(['categoryBrand']) // hasOne relation declared in Category model
      ->where([
        category_brand.product_id=:id //category_brand is table name
      ])
      ->params([':id'=>$id])
      ->one();
```

or try findBySql()

`$editCategory = Category::findBySql("SELECT * FROM category INNER JOIN category_brand ON category_brand.cat_id=category.cat_id WHERE category_brand.product_id=:id",['id'=>$id])->one();`

Comment: ok. i could've also done it with `print_r($editcat['category']);`